# I am trying to make a electro magnet. I bought a coil of enamel copper wire from Ebay. How do I determine its resistance?

Tags: resistance, resistivity

I didn't even know you need AWG rating to get a coil's resistance. But this is may sound naive, can I use the physics formula: $$R=\rho\frac{L}{A}$$.

\$\rho\$ is resistivity of copper, which I looked up to be \$0.000 000 017 W m\$. 
I know the length, \$L\$, is 100m. And the diameter is \$.5mm\$. So I know the cross-sectional area, \$A\$.

Now, my question is how accurate is the result?

Here is the website where I bought the coil:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/142313954017

Comment: You measure it with a multimeter.

Comment: I dont have one

Comment: That generally is a problematic thing when doing anything with electronics.

Comment: Which multimeter should I buy

Comment: any that turns out to be good after doing some research on your own on the topic. You might want to start with what one is and how to use it and how not to kill yourself. If you are the kind that loves videos, I recommend watching all multimeter related eevblog videos on youtube.

Comment: I cannot agree too strongly with PlasmaHH. If you don't get a meter, you will be trying to fix problems blind. You will have no way to tell what anything is doing. And trust me, you WILL make mistakes in building circuits. You have no idea how many dumb mistakes a person can make until you've made some of them yourself. Parts backward, wrong pins connected, accidental short circuits when two leads or wires accidentally touch... the list goes on. Go to a suppler like digikey.com and get a cheap meter. DO NOT go on eBay and get the cheapest Chinese meter you see.

Comment: Chivese Vici VC99 is fine for a starter

Comment: But i wonder, what will you do with electromagnet?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Electromagnets are fun...

Comment: Yes. Hadron colliders are more fun. Maybe this just a beginning?

Comment: And as I read the eBay link, the diameter is 0.2 mm, not 0.5

Comment: A multimeter, especially a cheap one, won't necessarily be that useful for measuring the low resistance of a hand-wound electromagnet.  However, it's not a bad thing to have around for *other* purposes.

Comment: Being eBay, you may not know if the copper is (0.2 or 0.5 mm) or if the copper **and enamel coating** are that size, so you're back to know knowing the copper cross sectional area. ...aaaaand - buy a meter.

Answer (score 6):

> And the diameter is .5mm

I'd look it up on google and find a table like this: -

[image]

Your diameter of 0.5 mm lies somewhere between 24 and 25 AWG and this means a 100 metre length will have about 9 ohms.

> Now, my question is how accurate is the result?

It will vary with temperature - hotter means higher resistance. At 20 degC copper has a resistivity of 1.68E-8 ohm-metres so using your formula I get a 0.5mm diameter wire of 100 metre length to be 8.57 ohms.

But it also depends on impurities in the copper: -

[image]

Only the "pure copper" trace aligns with the calculations above because there are no impurities. Now I'm not saying your vendor has added any nickel into the alloy but if you do eventually get an ohm meter and measure it, this might be an explanation.

Above picture taken from [here](http://www.transtutors.com/questions/-thermal-impurity-and-deformation-contributions-to-the-resistivity-are-indicated-at--686156.htm).

Comment: Please read the eBay link. Diameter is 0.2 mm.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes it is so, why did the op write 0.5mm? Anyway, the method is the same whether 0.2 mm or 0.5 mm diameter.

Comment: "why did the op write 0.5mm?" Why indeed. I can't insert a "roll your eyes" in comment.